# Unable to retrieve a Sitecore Item

Tags: sitecore-api, commerce-engine

I am trying to retrieve a `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` using this line:

```
var myItem = Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/x");
```

but instead of an Item I get a null exception. I have also tried

```
var myItem = Context.Data.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/x")
```

with same result. It seems like Database is null and when I try to veryfy that with:

```
var databases = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabases();
```

I get an empty list back. I have also tried to get a database item directly with:

```
string databaseName = "master";
var db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(databaseName);
```

but that gave me another exception

> Message = "Could not find configuration node:
>   databases/database[@id='master']"

At other places in the code it works fine to retrive Sitecore Items. Where it does work, I have a CommercePipelineExecutionContext (even though I don't directly uses it. Where it doesn't work I have a CommerceContext in which I have not found any database info. Any pointers to why this isn't working in this spot when it does work in others are appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing this on a hardened CD server where it has no master DB in the config?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in a config file (not sure though) since other parts of the code are able to access the master db.

Answer (score 2):

You can use method:

**public static ItemModel GetItemById(CommerceContext commerceContext, string itemId, string language = null)** from class **Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionManager**

You can use it in next way:

```
 var itemModel=SitecoreConnectionManager.GetItemById(context.CommerceContext,"{id}",en);
```

Here is the method definition:

```
public static ItemModel GetItemById(CommerceContext commerceContext, string itemId, string language = null)
    {
        ItemModel result;
        try
        {
            Guid guid;
            if (!Guid.TryParse(itemId, out guid))
            {
                commerceContext.Logger.LogError("SitecoreConnectionManager: ItemId is not a valid GUID.", Array.Empty<object>());
                result = null;
            }
            else
            {
                SitecoreConnectionPolicy policy = commerceContext.GetPolicy<SitecoreConnectionPolicy>();
                string action = string.IsNullOrEmpty(language) ? string.Format("sitecore/api/ssc/item/{0}?database={1}", itemId, policy.SitecoreDatabase) : string.Format("sitecore/api/ssc/item/{0}?database={1}&language={2}", itemId, policy.SitecoreDatabase, SitecoreConnectionManager.GetLanguage(commerceContext, language));
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = SitecoreConnectionManager.ProcessRequest(commerceContext, action, "GET", null);
                if (httpResponseMessage == null || !httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    result = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemModel>(httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            commerceContext.LogException("SitecoreConnectionManager", ex);
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, normally I could. In this case that won't work since I don't have access to the itemId (sorry for not mention that in the original question). The item I need to fetch I only have the Item name (which also is the last part of the item path).

Comment: if you are using public static List<ItemModel> GetItemsByPath(CommerceContext commerceContext, string path, string language = null) does it work for you?

Comment: I had to search in a bucket media items and I build myself a SSC api controller

Comment: Not sure how that would help me since the problem I am facing is that  `Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabases()` returns nothing. It seems like I don't have a database to call `GetItem()` on.

Comment: you don't have to call GetDatabases, you need to use SitecoreConnectionManager, is normal behaviour to crash call of Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabases() because you are not in Sitecore Context